# Is there a generic way to negate a decltype condition with SFINAE?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, generics, sfinae

I have a dozen functions or so that take two parameters: a generic, and a specific type. E.g.:

```
template <class A, class B>
void foo(A& a, B& b)
{
    cout << "generic fallback" << endl;
}

template <class A>
void foo(A& a, int &i)
{
    cout << "generic int" << endl;
}

template <class A>
void foo(A& a, string& s)
{
    cout << "generic str" << endl;
}
```

I want to create an overload which will get called whenever `A` is an instance of a particular struct[1]. The best I came up with so far was:

```
struct mine
{
    int is_special;
};

template <class A, class B>
auto foo(A& a, B& b) -> decltype(A::is_special, void())
{
    cout << "specialized fallback" << endl;
}
```

The result I want is:

```
int x;
string y;
float z;
string generic;
mine special;

foo(generic, x); // generic int
foo(generic, y); // generic string
foo(generic, z); // generic fallback
foo(special, x); // specialized fallback
foo(special, y); // specialized fallback
foo(special, z); // specialized fallback
```

The above code doesn't work, however, because for the specialized cases, there is an ambiguous overload. Is there any easy way to cause those functions to only get created if `A::is_special` is not a valid type? Ideally I would annotate each function with something like:

```
template <class A, class B>
auto foo(A& a, B& b) -> decltype(doesnt_work(A::is_special), void())
// ...
```

I ask also in the more general case: given any "positive" SFINAE test which results in a function or class getting created as a result of the test, is there any way to negate that test specifically for use in other cases? In essence, the equivalent of `if ... else if` with SFINAE.

I did get this case to work, but I had to rename all `foo` to `foo_imp`, add a `long` parameter to the generic ones, an `int` parameter to the specialized one, and then define a `foo` that called them (ideone code [here](https://ideone.com/ds5So4)). This seems less-than-ideal in that it's not as straightforward, although either way I have to modify all the existing `foo`s anyway.

---

[1] Note that I can't use the type's name because it is a nested template and would thus result in a non-deducible context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In essence, the equivalent of `if ... else if` with SFINAE.

You can manually control overload resolution with an extra parameter:

```
template<int I> struct rank : rank<I-1> { static_assert(I > 0, ""); };
template<> struct rank<0> {};

template <class A, class B>
auto foo(A& a, B& b, rank<10>) -> /*some SFINAE */
{
}

template <class A, class B>
auto foo(A& a, B& b, rank<9>) -> /* some other SFINAE */
{
}

// ...

template <class A, class B>
void foo(A& a, B& b, rank<0>)
{
// fallback
}

template <class A, class B>
void foo(A& a, B& b) { return foo(a, b, rank<20>()); }
```

The viable overload with the highest "rank" will be selected by overload resolution.

You can't directly negate an *ad hoc* SFINAE constraint ("this expression used in the signature must be well-formed"). You'll need to write an actual trait to detect it, and then negate the result. Simplest way to do it is probably by using  [`std::experimental::is_detected_v`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected), recently voted into v2 of the library fundamentals TS:

```
template<class T>
using is_special_t = decltype(T::is_special);

template <class A, class B>
auto foo(A& a, B& b) -> std::enable_if_t<!std::experimental::is_detected_v<is_special_t, A>>
{
    cout << "generic fallback" << endl;
}

template <class A, class B>   
auto foo(A& a, B& b) -> std::enable_if_t<std::experimental::is_detected_v<is_special_t, A>>
{
    cout << "specialized fallback" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, a template to check whether a given type is "special":

```
template<typename ...> using void_t = void;

template< typename, typename = void >
struct is_special : public std::false_type {};

template< typename T >
struct is_special<T, void_t<decltype(T::is_special)> > : public std::true_type {};
```

Instead of the `void_t`, you could also use your `decltype(T::is_special, void() )` construct.

Next, you can plug in some SFINAE expressions which enable/disable the relevant functions depending on the passed types. The following code particularly disables any generic callback for your special type.

```
template <class A, class B, typename = std::enable_if_t<!is_special<A>::value> >
void foo(A& a, B& b)
{
    cout << "generic fallback" << endl;
}

template <class A, typename = std::enable_if_t<!is_special<A>::value>>
void foo(A& a, int &i)
{
    cout << "generic int" << endl;
}

template <class A, typename = std::enable_if_t<!is_special<A>::value>>
void foo(A& a, string& s)
{
    cout << "generic str" << endl;
}

//this SFINAE check is probably redundant    
template <class A, class B, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_special<A>::value> >   
auto foo(A& a, B& b)
{
    cout << "specialized fallback" << endl;
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfdfcf33e53152f2)

Note that the last check for `is_special` in the specialized fallback is probably redundant.

Comment: Nice.. this seems the closest to what I asked for: a way to specify an arbitrary trait (with `decltype`) and then negate it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;
```

`std::void_t` is not in C++11.  The above will work in every C++11 compiler I've tried it on.  (a one-step alias breaks some compilers due to a C++11 language defect)

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply : std::false_type {};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, /*std::*/ void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>: std::true_type {};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;
```

this takes a template `Z` and a pack of parameters `Ts...`, and returns `true_type` iff `Z<Ts...>` is a valid expression.

```
template<class T>
using is_special_t = decltype( T::is_special );
```

takes a `T`, and returns its `is_special` type.

```
template<class T>
using has_special = can_apply< is_special_t, T >;
```

solves your problem.

This is similar in function to [`std::experimental::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected), but is an independent implementation.